# Using JSON value as IN operator in Postgres SQL

Tags: json, database, postgresql

I've two tables like below

### Table 1 : users

id - number

authorization  - json

| id | user_name | authorized_customers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | ["002*001*A", "002001B","002001ABC"] |
| 2 | user2 | ["002001A", "002001Z","002001ABZ"] |

Table 2: orders

id - number,

user_id - number - forigen key of users table

name - varchar

customer  - varchar

| id | customer_name | customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 002001A |
| 2 | doe | 002001Z |

My question is:

How do I get all orders based on the user1's authorized customer like

select * from orders where customer in(select CAST(json_array_elements(authorized_customers) AS VARCHAR) AS customer_ids from users where id=1)

Any help is appreciated.

I tired above query but no value returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE customer IN (
    SELECT json_array_elements_text(authorized_customers) AS customer_ids 
    FROM users 
    WHERE id = 1
)
```

make sure that you have db indexes on `users.id` and `orders.customer` columns. It can greatly improve the performance.
How does `json_array_elements_text` work?:
example users data:

```
id | user_name | authorized_customers
-----------------------------------------
1  | user1     | ["002001A", "002001B","002001ABC"]
2  | user2     | ["002001A", "002001Z","002001ABZ"]
```

query like:

```
SELECT json_array_elements_text(authorized_customers) FROM users WHERE id = 1;
```

will make this output:

```
json_array_elements_text
--------------------------
002001A
002001B
002001ABC
```

Comment: @user3593900 does it make sense?

Comment: Thank you Baktybek Baiserkeev, this solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres supports a number of operators for dealing with JSON; in this case you can use the `json ? text -> boolean` operator [as described in the official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

Something like:

```
select * 
from orders o
join users u on u.authorized_customers ? o.customer
where u.id = 1
```

will return records where the o.customer value is in the JSON array u.authorized_customers.

Comment: Thank you George S, this solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go with **json_array_elements_text** function. It will extract the data from the array.

Here is how to execute query:

```
SELECT * FROM orders o JOIN users u ON o.customer = ANY(json_array_elements_text(u.authorized_customers))
WHERE u.id = 1;
```

The join is being performed on basis of

`o.customer = ANY(json_array_elements_text(u.authorized_customers))`

Value is returned if any of the value matches.